# Fetch list of sites in site collection into jQuery

Tags: jquery, client-object-model, ajax

Is there a way to get the list of sites in the current site collection into jQuery as an array or other data structure? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the ECMA Script Client Object Model:

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(loadWebs, "sp.js");

    function loadWebs() {

       var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();

       this.webs = clientContext.get_web().get_webs();

       clientContext.load(this.webs);

       clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onWebsLoaded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));

    }

    function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

       alert('request failed ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());

    }

    function onWebsLoaded(sender, args) {

       for (var i = 0; i < this.webs.get_count(); i++) {

       alert(this.webs.itemAt(i).get_title());

       }    
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, Vardhaman. Where did you get the syntax for the Client Object Model? Is there documentation on SharePoint/JavaScript? Thanks.

Comment: Here is the MSDN link for the classes:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee557057.aspx

also check out the following MSDN article series:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdev/archive/2011/07/13/working-with-the-ecmascript-client-object-model-jsom-in-sharepoint-2010-part-1-nikhil-sachdeva.aspx

Comment: It's giving me a JavaScript error: `SP.ClientContext is undefined`. I just noticed that the JS file in my page layout loads before the required SP.js files are loaded; any way to fix this?

Comment: I have edited the original code. see the ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded function.

Comment: Thanks, Vardhaman. It worked like a charm once I added the `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded()` function. Also, I placed it inside the jQuery `$(document).ready()` function. By the way, if we run this from a site, it seems to only return that site's title; does it need to be run from a master page for the entire site collection to return all sites?